# Java Division Of Integer With Brackets

Tags: java, android, integer, division

In my app I ask the user to provide their hourly rate, I then have a Chronometer which I want to work out how much they have earned since the time started. To do this I need to turn their hourly rate into a seconds rate and multiply it by the seconds from the Chronometer.

```
        timer.setOnChronometerTickListener(new Chronometer.OnChronometerTickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer chronometer){
            long timeElapsed = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - timer.getBase();
            int hours = (int) (timeElapsed / 3600000);
            int minutes = (int) (timeElapsed - hours * 3600000) / 60000;
            int seconds = (int) (timeElapsed - hours * 3600000 - minutes * 60000) / 1000;

            int hrlyRate = Integer.parseInt(hourlyRate.getText().toString());

            secondsRate = (hrlyRate / 60) / 60;
            moneyEarned = secondsRate * seconds;

            Log.d("hrlyRate", Integer.toString(hrlyRate));
            Log.d("secondsRate", Integer.toString(secondsRate));


        }
    });
```

Say the user enters 40 into the hourlyRate field which I get from an EditText, why is the calculation of secondsRate = 0? Shouldn't it be (40 / 60) / 60 = $0.01 / second?

Answer (score 0):

try this (use float/double instead of int and 60.0f/60.0 instead of 60, for example)

```
timer.setOnChronometerTickListener(new Chronometer.OnChronometerTickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer chronometer){
        double timeElapsed = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - timer.getBase();
        double hours = (double) (timeElapsed / 3600000.0);
        double minutes = (double) (timeElapsed - hours * 3600000.0) / 60000.0;
        double seconds = (double) (timeElapsed - hours * 3600000.0 - minutes * 60000.0) / 1000;

        double hrlyRate = Double.parseDouble(hourlyRate.getText().toString());

        secondsRate = (hrlyRate / 60.0) / 60.0;
        moneyEarned = secondsRate * seconds;

        Log.d("hrlyRate", Double.toString(hrlyRate));
        Log.d("secondsRate", Double.toString(secondsRate));


    }
});
```